# Making class immutable with interface constructor argument type

Tags: java

I'm self-studying computer science in my free time and currently taking Berkeley's CS61B class, which has materials posted online. I've been able to figure out most things myself, but am stuck on one point on a homework assignment. The spec is here: https://sp18.datastructur.es/materials/hw/hw4/hw4

The challenge is that the Solver class should be immutable. The Solver class has the following API:

```
public class Solver {
    public Solver(WorldState initial)
    public int moves()
    public Iterable<WorldState> solution()
}
```

WorldState is an interface, not a class, as follows:

```
package hw4.puzzle;

public interface WorldState {
    /** Provides an estimate of the number of moves to reach the goal.
     * Must be less than or equal to the correct distance. */
    int estimatedDistanceToGoal();

    /** Provides an iterable of all the neighbors of this WorldState. */
    Iterable<WorldState> neighbors();

    /** Estimates the distance to the goal. Must be less than or equal
     *  to the actual (and unknown) distance. */
    default public boolean isGoal() {
      return estimatedDistanceToGoal() == 0;
    }
}
```

Thus, I don't have any way to copy the argument to the Solver constructor. If a program calls solver with an initial WorldState, then changes that WorldState, the Solver solution will also reflect the change since it holds a reference to the object passed in. The solutions I've been able to find get around this by making Solver specifically take as an argument an implementation of WorldState that is within the package, so they can create a new object of that type and copy the argument over to it. But the assignment is supposed to maintain generality in the Solver class.

One thing I tried to do is create an implementation of WolrdState as a subclass of Solver that takes as arguments an int estimatedDistanceToGoal and Iterable neighbors variables, and then the implementation of the interface methods would return those values directly. I didn't get it to work, however, as other parts of the assignment recast the WorldState objects to a specific implementation (Board) that was passed in as the initial arg, and it breaks here. It would also be a ton of overhead.

Any other ideas or ways to point me in the right direction? I know the course reasonably seeks to prevent solutions from leaking online, so perhaps a PM response would be more suitable or just a hint rather than a solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, it is quite clear. the requirement is that `Solver` should somehow keep a separate copy of `WolrdState` (arg to ctor) instead of a reference - to shield it from external modifications. if `WolrdState` would extend `Cloneable` that would solve it.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, you are not right about `Cloneable`. It is just marker interface and you don't need it to perform clone. Also you it wouldn't help you at all as any class implementing `WorldState` could override method `clone` and you cant rely on that.

Comment: @AndreiMakarevich `Cloneable` is indeed a marker interface but if the concrete class does not implement `clone()` then `Object`'s `clone()` checks if the class implements the marker interface and throws an exception. in other worlds, you cannot "blindly" call `clone()` and expect it to "just work"

Comment: @SharonBenAsher but implementing Clonable doesn’t guarantee that implementing classes will override clone. So in this case ypu will still get just a shallow copy of all inner objects.

Comment: @AndreiMakarevich when implementing `Clonable` there is no guarentee other than be able to call `clone()` successfully. it is expected that a class that implements   `Clonable` will also implement `clone()` method. that ls the way the clone mechanism works in Java. there is no other way for a method that recevies reference to interface to make a copy of the object. the only other way I know of a copy ctor and there is no way to know if one exists other than reflection

Comment: @AndreiMakarevich. after a quick online research, i see that implementing `Clonable` is regarded as **mandatory** even if the class implement the `clone()` method because the method should call `super.clone()` (especially if it has a super class other than `Object`)

Answer (score 0):

The WorldState implementation should be immutable as well. The assignment tells you to create an immutable class named Board that implements WorldState.

If that wasn't the case you could still make Solver immutable by cloning the WorldState you pass as an argument to the constructor, and declaring the property that stores it as final and private.

Keep in mind that the state of an object can't be altered if you want it to be immutable, but you can construct a new object that has the alterations you want.
Documentation has a good [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) of the difference between a mutable class and an immutable one that have essentially no difference in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> Immutable class means that once an object is created, we cannot change
>   its content.

I can see, that `WorldState` implementation is immutable, because it contains only getters or calculation. So, you need just save this reference to the

```
public final class Solver {
    private final WorldState initial;

    public Solver(WorldState initial) {
        this.initial = initial;
    }

    public int moves() {
        // should not modify internal state; only calculation
    }

    public Iterable<WorldState> solution() {
        // should not modify internal state; only calculation
    }
}
```

Finally, `Solver` class could be treated as immutable when it does not change it's state and state of all it's variables, like `initial`.

Comment: you can only assume that implementations of `WorldState` are immutable. this is not guarenteed. perhaps it is enough in the scope of the exercise, but to be 100% immutable you would have to clone the arg